# Comparing multiple arrays on blade

Tags: laravel, relationship, jquery-select2, laravel-blade

I have an array called a **catalog** that has a relationship with several **stores**.
I get them with this command on controller.
There are **users** they also have relationship with several **stores**.

```
  $stores = $user->store()->get(); 
  $catalog = $user->catalog()->with('store')->get();
  return view('manager.catalogs.manage', compact('stores', 'catalog'));
```

I want to select the user’s existing stores via select2, and link them to the catalogs (catalogs also have link with store). In this case, the user's stores linked to catalog must be pre-selected.

The problem I have is that there are a few catalogs and a few stores here.

```
    $catalog = $user->catalog()->with('store')->get();
```

But one user only has store.

```
   $stores = $user->store()->get();
```

How can compare user stores with catalogs store and select existing ones in the selectbox?

```
<select class="select2 form-control max-length" multiple>
  @foreach($stores as $store)
    @if($catalog->store->id === $store_id)
      <option value="{{$store->id}}" selected>{{$store->name}}</option>
    @else
      <option value="{{$store->id}}">{{$store->name}}</option>
    @endif
 @endforeach
</select>
```

Tables

**user**
id | username

**catalogs**
id | name | user_id

**stores**
id | name | user_id

**catalog_stores**
id| catalog_id | store_id

Please help solve this.
Laravel version 8.40